# How to make my own timestamp method in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

Typically, the Laravel platform have a `$table->timestamps();`
in migration..., it generate two `datetime` fields,
But I would like to implement my own timestamps or, maybe call `unix_timestamps()`. I would like to have two fields named `created_at`, and `updated_at`, and which store the unix timestamps, how can I implement it? Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming you want the same features as with $table->timestamp(), i.e. auto updating timestamps? Otherwise $table->integer('created_at') should work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to use Laravel's timestamp helpers, but they are convenient.  There are some good ways of working with string timestamps now too, including PHP's [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class.  But I digress, to use unix timestamps...

1. In your Schema (migration), use

   ```
    $table->integer('created_at');
    $table->integer('updated_at');
   ```

instead of

```
    $table->timestamps();
```

2. Replace the `timestamp()` function in your models.
3. Keep `$timestamps = true` in your models.

Here's an example base model which you could use, and extend instead of Eloquent on your models:

```
// models/basemodel.php
class BaseModel extends Eloquent {

    /**
     * Indicates if the model has update and creation timestamps.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public static $timestamps = true;

    /**
     * Set the update and creation timestamps on the model.
     */
    public function timestamp()
    {
        $this->updated_at = time();

        if ( ! $this->exists) $this->created_at = $this->updated_at;
    }
}

// models/thing.php
class Thing extends BaseModel {

}
```

Answer (score 4):

For Laravel 4:

- override the freshTimestamp() method in your Eloquent model
- use integers in migration file in stead of timestamps

**models/product.php**

```
class Product extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'products';

    public function freshTimestamp()
    {
        return time();
    }
}
```

Laravel 4 also mutates all dates/timestamps to Carbon instances (Documented [here](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#date-mutators))

Which means you also need to overwrite the `getDates()` method in order to prevent Carbon ruining your timestamp before insertion.

```
public function getDates()
{
    return array();
}
```

**database/migrations/2013_04_20_125823_create_products_table.php** :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('created_at');
        $table->integer('updated_at');
    });
}
```

Comment: This method worked for me, however, on related tables I had to disabled the "touches" property because I was getting an InvalidArgumentException when running `db:seed`. I don't have the time to look into exactly why this is at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

I fear that you'll need some ugly hacks in order to rewrite the `timestamps()` function, and I'm sure that's a bad idea.

If you need your own format, simply define a new column. There is even a timestamp column in Laravel's schema builder (see [here](http://laravel.com/docs/database/schema#adding-columns) for a full list of available formats):

```
$table->timestamp('added_on');
```

You would however need to define default values and/or `ON UPDATE` by yourself, or you could use [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html). But in the end you're probably best off sticking to Laravel's `timestamps()`, because it will take care of everything automatically. Why would you need anything else?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same requirement and figured out a solution that may work for you too. I posted a repo of how I did it on Github: [Laravel Integer SQL Dates](https://github.com/jhauraw/laravel-integer-sql-dates) <== check it out for more details, but here's the gist of it:

```php
class Base extends Eloquent {

  public function freshTimestamp()
  {
    return time(); // (int) instead of '2000-00-00 00:00:00'
  }

  public function fromDateTime($value)
  {
    return $value; // Don't mutate our (int) on INSERT!
  }

  // Uncomment, if you don't want Carbon API on SELECTs
  // protected function asDateTime($value)
  // {
  //   return $value;
  // }

  public function getDateFormat()
  {
    return 'U'; // PHP date() Seconds since the Unix Epoch
  }
}

class User extends Base {

  protected $table = 'users';

  protected $fillable = ['email'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a migrations/model field that is a timestamp type, then in your controller, fill it with current time using this

```
$myField = new \DateTime();
```